# Converting Integer number into hexadecimal number in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

**Write a program to convert an integer number to its hexadecimal representation without using inbuilt functions.**

Here is my code, but it is not working. Can anyone tell where is the mistake?

It is giving an error:

> "Project raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 00453B7B in module 'Project.exe'.Write of address FFFFFFFF'.Process stopped.Use Step or Run to continue."

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,     Controls,Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  end;
function hexvalue(num:Integer):Char;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
function hexvalue(num:Integer):Char;
  begin
    case num of
      10: Result:='A';
      11: Result:='B';
      12: Result:='C';
      13: Result:='D';
      14: Result:='E';
      15: Result:='F';
    else Result:=Chr(num);
  end;
end;

var
  intnumber,hexnumber,actualhex:String;
  integernum:Integer;
  i,j,k:Byte;

begin
  InputQuery ('Integer Number','Enter the integer number', intnumber);
  integernum:=StrToInt(intnumber);
  i:=0;
  while integernum >= 16 do
    begin
      hexnumber[i]:=hexvalue(integernum mod 16);
      integernum:= integernum div 16;
      Inc(i);
    end;
  hexnumber[i]:= hexvalue(integernum);
  k:=i;
  for j:=0 to k do
     begin
      actualhex[j]:= hexnumber[i];
      Dec(i);
    end;
  ShowMessage(actualhex);

end.
```

Comment: `Result:=Chr(num);` is highly suspicious. For example, `Chr(3)` is *not* equal to `'3'`. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII.

Comment: Chr($ffffffff)? ......

Comment: Too many errors... 1) You don't set a length for `hexnumber`, so you can't access it by indexing chars (`hexnumber[i]`), because those char indexes don't exist. 2) `Chr(num)` is totally wrong. `Chr(3)` won't do what you think. 3) Your `case` only handles 10..15 properly; what happens if `num` = 17, 23, 64, or 99? 4) You mix various data sizes willy-nilly. 5) See #1, replacing all instances of `hexnumber` with `actualhex`.

Comment: @Ken White Error #3 that you mentioned would never occur because argument to hexvalue function is always (mod 16).

Comment: @Ansh43 I cannot see that specified in the question.

Comment: @Ansh43: That's not true, because there's no restriction that `hexvalue` won't be called from somewhere else later. The function should be designed properly to deal with *all possible input*.

Comment: @Ken That's a matter of policy. It's perfectly reasonable to have private internals functions that perform no input parameter validation. Certainly for perf critical functions that is essential. If the contract states that only values between 0 and 15 may be passed then that is fine. No such contract is visible though.

Comment: @David: I said that, didn't I? *there's no restriction that [it] won't be called from somewhere else*. That restriction would be the contract, no?

Comment: @Ken No. You said that the function must be written to deal with all possible input.

Comment: @David: Ah, here we go again. Quibbling over things you imagine were said  **in a comment**. Which is pretty interesting, considering I said exactly the same thing you did; the quibble this time is over vocabulary, and I didn't choose the exact words you approved for use. Oops. My bad. I'll run it by you first next time to make sure that you bless the words I use **commenting** in response to someone else.

Comment: @Ken I'm helping the user. It's just not so that all functions need to be robust to all possible input. I want the asker to know that. I imagined nothing. We are not saying the same thing all. You say "the function should be designed properly to deal with all possible input". I say that is not so.

Comment: @David: Ok. Explain your [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922807/converting-integer-number-into-hexadecimal-number-in-delphi-7?noredirect=1#comment49883397_30922807) *Chr($ffffffff)?*? If the function doesn't need to be robust, and it's OK to assume (artificially) that the code will only be called with a number between 0..15, then your comment is absolutely wrong. Again, I made the same point you did, but didn't use your approved vocabulary. A bit hypocritical, don't you think?

Comment: @Ken You are quite the most obnoxious person at times. Have some common decency. Please talk to me like I am a human being that deserves a basic level of respect. I made that comment before the asker announced that input was in the range 0 to 15. A contract that is still not visible in the Q as I later pointed out. Either the function validates input, or it trusts a contract that says it will receive valid input. Either design could be valid in certain situations.

Comment: @Ken My comment that started this little tiff was in response to you stating, as I read it, that the function could not trust its input and had to validate.

Comment: @David: And you are quite the most arrogant at times. My statement was that, *as there is nothing in place to validate input*, and *there is nothing to prevent this function from being called elsewhere with invalid input*, that it should test for valid input. (IOW, *there's no contract in place to assure valid data, so you should ensure valid data*.) A `case` statement should handle expected input, and either deal with unexpected input by defaulting to a safe value or raising an exception. A blind `else` with (as you noted) a possible invalid value being passed to `Chr()` doesn't do so.

Comment: And as far as it *being before the asker announced*, it was  *after* I pointed out to the asker that there was an issue that the asker *announced* the limitation. And as far as *basic level of respect*, I treat people as they treat me. If you want *respect*, then treat people with the same respect.

Comment: @KenWhite OK, well that's where I disagree. The contract is that the input is valid (0..15). We agree on that. We have two main options. We can check inputs and treat invalid inputs as explicit handled errors. Or we can assume that the input is valid and so not entertain the possibility that input will be invalid. The contract is the same, but we have to decide whether or not we trust the consumer to adhere to the contract. Both choices are valid in different circumstances.  cont...

Comment: @KenWhite We disagree fundamentally on what type of conduct is reasonable here. You are repeatedly abusive towards me.  I believe that your behaviour is wrong and against the site policies.  You believe that it is reasonable to be abusive in this way.  I hope that I never resort to insults and abuse in the way that you do (as seen above). I have an opinion that on this instance differs from yours. What can possibly be the problem with that?

Comment: @David: *repeatedly abusive*? I'm not the one that started name-calling here - you did that with *quite the most arrogant*, which is *quite* insulting and rude. You're also the one that said to the asker *I cannot see that specified in the question.* when the asker posted that error #3 could never occur. I don't see anything anywhere in the question that limits the visibility of the function to a specific scope, which was the point I was making.

Comment: @David: Certainly, if you're writing code you will use personally, and you can self-enforce validity of the values passed to the function, it's fine not to validate. I'd also presume that if you're providing that code to others, you will at least document the fact that there is a contract to pass only values within the `-1...1` range so they know it as well, or create a type that is limited to that range to allow the compiler to handle it.

Comment: @KenWhite It started here, with my emphasis. *Ah, **here we go again**. Quibbling over things you **imagine** were said in a comment. Which is pretty interesting, considering I said exactly the same thing you did; the quibble this time is over vocabulary, and I didn't choose the exact words you approved for use. **Oops. My bad. I'll run it by you first next time to make sure that you bless the words I use commenting in response to someone else** .... Again, I made the same point you did, but didn't use your **approved vocabulary**. A bit **hypocritical**, don't you think?* Please stop it.

Comment: @Ken And as for the technical matters, then we agree. Whether or not to use parameter validation depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @David: Ok. Whatever. On the technical matters, yes. We agree.

Answer (score 4):

Since this obviously is a homework assignment, I don't want to spoil it for you and write the solution, but rather attempt to guide you to the solution.

**User input**
In real code you would need to be prepared for any mistake from the user and check that the input really is integer numbers only and politely ask the user to correct the input if erroneous.

**Conversion loop**
You have got that OK, using `mod 16` for each nibble of `integernum` and `div 16` to move to the next nibble, going from units towards higher order values.

**Conversion of nibble to hex character**
Here you go wrong. If you would have written out also the cases for 0..9, you could have got the `case` statement right. As others have commented, `Chr()` takes an ASCII code. However, using a `case` statement for such a simple conversion is tedious to write and not very efficient.
What if you would have a lookup table (array) where the index (0..15) directly would give you the corresponding hex character. That would be much simpler. Something like

```
const
  HexChars: array[_.._] of Char = ('0',_____'F')
```

I leave it to you to fill in the missing parts.

**Forming the result (hex string)**
Your second major mistake and the reason for the AV is that you did not set the length of the string `hexnumber` before attempting to acess the character positions. Another design flaw is that you fill in `hexnumber` backwards. As a result you then need an extra loop where you reverse the order to the correct one.
There are at least two solutions to solve both problems:

1. Since you take 32 bit `integer` type input, the hex representation is not more than 8 characters. Thus you can preset the length of the string to 8 and fill it in from the lower order position using `8 - i` as index. As a final step you can trim the string if you like.
2. Don't preset the length and just concatenate as you go in the loop    `hexnumber := HexChars[integernum mod 16] + hexnumber;`.

**Negative values**
You did not in any way consider the possibility of negative values in your code, so I assume it wasn't part of the task.

Answer (score 3):

First mistake : String are 1 indexed. Meaning that the index of their first character is 1 and not 0. You initialize "i" to 0 and then try to set hexnumber[i].

Second mistake : Strings might be dynamic, but they don't grow automatically. If you try to access the first character of an empty string, it won't work. You need to call SetLength(HeXNumber, *NumberOfDigits*). You can calculate the number of digits this way :

```
NumberOfDigits := Trunc(Log16(integernum)) + 1;
```

Since Log16 isn't really something that exists, you can either use LogN(16,integernum) or (Log(IntegerNum) / Log(16)) depending on what is available in your version of Delphi.

Note that this might return an invalid value for very, very large value (high INT64 range) due to rounding errors.

If you don't want to go that road, you could replace the instruction by

```
hexnumber := hexvalue(integernum mod 16) + hexnumber;
```

which would also remove the need to invert the string at the end.

Third Mistake : Using unsigned integer for loop variable.  While this is debatable, the instruction

```
for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
```

is common practice in Delphi without checking `Count > 0`. When count = 0 and using an unsigned loop counter, you'll either get an integer overflow (if you have them activated in your project options) or you'll loop High(I) times, which isn't what you want to be doing.

Fourth mistake : already mentionned : `Result:=Chr(num)` should be replaced by something like  `Result := InttoStr(Num)[1]`.
Personally, I'd implement the function using an array.

```
HexArr : Array[0..15] of char = ('0', '1',...,'D','E','F');
begin
  if InRange(Num, 0, 15) then
    Result := HexArr[Num]
  else
    //whatever you want
end;
```